# Selenium web driver: cannot be scrolled into view

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE and Selenium web driver testng in eclipse ..
my testing is against ZK application ..

the test case works fine on Selenium IDE ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://*****/>
<title>work it2</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">work it2</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/xxx</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//li[2]/div/div/div/span</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td>3000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>doubleClick</td>
    <td>//div[2]/div[2]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td>3000</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I run it in eclipse with selenium web driver (testng) I got an error ..

```
    selenium.open("xxx");
selenium.click("//li[2]/div/div/div/span");
Thread.sleep(3000);
selenium.doubleClick("//div[2]/div[2]");
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

I also changed the code to

```
 driver.get("xxx");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[2]/div/div/div/span")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        WebElement ee = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div[2]"));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.doubleClick(ee).perform();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
```

also getting the same error ...

### the error was in this line

```
//div[2]/div[2]
```

> com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Offset within element
>   cannot be scrolled into view: (87, 118): [object XrayWrapper [object
>   HTMLDivElement]] Command duration or timeout: 63 milliseconds Build
>   info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16
>   16:11:15' System info: host: 'EnD', ip: '192.168.17.76', os.name:
>   'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.7.0_51' Session ID: 3b79783c-2558-4c87-bd51-a72821696040 Driver
>   info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true,
>   takesScreenshot=true, version=27.0.1}]

Comment: the error appear on this line in eclipse selenium.doubleClick("//div[2]/div[2]");

Comment: The doubleClick xpath in your IDE example is different from the WebDriver code.  Is this on purpose?

Comment: sorry it was a mistake !

Comment: I am really stuck here , any help?

Comment: That type of error may occur because the element you are trying to click is not visible.  However, that is a guess.  It is hard to help without the same problem occuring on our computers.  Can you create an example page on jsfiddle.net that has the same issue?  Often, making a simple test case helps you find out the problem on your own.

Answer (score 11):

Naif,

Actually, your above question is different than the actual question hence you should have asked it as a separate question. Still, I'm answering to your previous question.

The error is because the element you're trying to click on isn't visible. Before you click on element, it should be visible. You can do this by following -

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div[2]"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); //here, wait time is 20 seconds

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)); //this will wait for elememt to be visible for 20 seconds
element.click(); //now it clicks on element
```

If above doesn't work, you can click on element by executing javascript(but this isn't a good practice)

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Thanks , but it did not work either .. I am sure the element is visible on the browser.. and it works fine with selenium IDE .. But no idea why is not working in the web driver !

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for visibility of [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (d6ae4ad6-057c-460b-a730-a52f05fb536f)] -> xpath: //div[2]/div[2]]

Comment: Please try with Javascript part, it will surely work.

Comment: WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div[2]"));
     
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
          js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Comment: I'm not sure about double click but give a try with - `(JavascriptExecutor)driver; js.executeScript("arguments[0].dblclick();", element); `

Comment: Hi from the future. Scrolling down into view did not work for me, even though the element was already in view. What did work was the `.click` through the `executeScript` function. In python, the API call was `js.execute_script("argument[0].click();", element). Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 6):

Try to execute the script and click the element

```
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: Thanks. executeScript() is working here with javascript API and Firefox 68. I guess the error with the default click() function only occurs when clicking an element inside a ./table/tr/td.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but try and see if following works for you. First, you've to make that element visible before interacting with it -

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div[2]"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

The above code will scroll down till the element is visible and then you can click on it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error in slightly different context where I was trying to click anchor tag with the selenium RemoteWebDriver (I was trying to replace WebDriver). The fix was identifying the right set of capability for the driver for eg:

`capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
 capability.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
 capability.setCapability("version", "66");`

Answer (score 0):

I just resized my browser dimensions and it worked like so

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(SOME_URL)
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
```

Comment: Note: I did this in python but I imagine the same method in Java might work.