# Selenium FirefoxDriver hover

Tags: java, selenium

Trying to automatically create a website in weebly and everything works fine untill I get to the theme choosing page. There you need to hover over a picture so the choosing button will be visible. My code so far.

```
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);      
driver.get("https://www.weebly.com");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("weebly-username")).sendKeys("johndoe@mail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("weebly-password")).sendKeys("everest777);
driver.findElement(By.className("login-btn")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.className("site-selector__btn")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.className("site-switcher-group__item--add-site")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.className("w-icon-li-blog")).click();

Actions hover=new Actions(driver);
hover.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt='Slick']"))).perform();
driver.findElement(By.className("btn")).click();
```

After execution it stops before hovering over the image and gives `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view:`exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
hover.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt='Slick']"))).build.perform();
```

Then you should wait for a while for the elements to show up before clicking.

Comment: Usually i see this error when the element is not visible yet and I try to access it somehow. Did you included the wait command after you moved to the element?

Comment: I use:        Actions hover = new Actions(driver);
        hover.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt='Slick']"))).build().perform(); r
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.className("btn")).click(); But still same error

Comment: Is the item you are dealing with present in the same window or it switches to a new window? If it is the same window, try identifying the element using xpath or any other identifier.

Comment: Furthermore , you can have a look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588096/selenium-web-driver-cannot-be-scrolled-into-view)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I followed that link and solved it with the javascript example.