# Selenium: Element could not be scrolled into view

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to learn Selenium using java with Eclipse. I am trying to locate one element in the webpage.

I tried using this line of code to click on one html `<a>` element:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='itemDetail.php?id=19']")).click();
```

The picture below shows the html structure of the page:

[image]

With that piece of code, I ran into an exception:

> Element `<a href="itemDetail.php?id=19">` could not be scrolled into
>   view

Did I use the wrong syntax to locate the element?

Thank you for the advice.

Comment: The exception doesn't say that the element doesn't exist. It was located, but it is not visible and cannot be clicked on.

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/q/22588096/4513879

Answer (score 4):

The locator looks good as you haven't received NoSuchElement exception. Try the below javascript click, which does not need the element to be scrolled into view.

**JavaScript Click**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='itemDetail.php?id=19']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",element);
```

If you want to scroll the element into view and the do normal click user the below code.

**Scrolling into view and normal click:**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='itemDetail.php?id=19']"));    
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",element);
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

To *locate* and `click()` on the desired `<a>` element you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='container']//figcaption[text()='Play-Doh Rainbow Starter Pack']//preceding::img[1]"))).click();
```