# How to click custom HTML tag with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to download a few hundred excel files from `sellercentral.amazon.de`. As mentioned in my previous post, manual download is not an option, as I need to make several clicks to get to download popup.

In order to do so, I'm using Python and Selenium.

**The Problem**

However, the website to scrape doesnt simply consist of buttons and links, but custom tags as well. One of these is the tag 'browse-node-component', each of which represents a product (sub-)category. Finding it is no big deal, but the click on it doesn't get executed. The clicks are needed to navigate through the categories to it's children, until a leaf node is reached. The Icon then changes from an arrow to 'select' (see imgur).

The code I've tried so far is:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("browse-node-component")

for element in elements:

    print("starting")

    # Store element name    
    browse_node = element.find_element_by_class_name("browse-node-text")
    browse_node = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "browse-node-text")))

    browse_node_button = element.find_element_by_class_name("a-button-input")
    print ("done")
    browse_node_button.click()
```

**Exemplary "browse-node-component"-tag**

```
    <span>
        <div class="a-section a-spacing-none browse-node selected-node" ng-class="(nodeCtrl.node.hasChildren ? 'browse-node' : 'leaf-node') + ' ' + (nodeCtrl.isSelected ? 'selected-node' : '')" ng-click="nodeCtrl.node.hasChildren &amp;&amp; nodeCtrl.onBrowseChildren({node:nodeCtrl.node});">

            <div class="browse-node-text ng-binding" style="">Auto &amp; Motorrad</div>

            <div class="node-icon-btn-block">

                <img class="loading-icon ng-hide" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/abis-ui/loading-small._CB192205764_.gif" ng-show="nodeCtrl.isLoading">
                <div class="lock-icon ng-hide" ng-show="nodeCtrl.isGated"></div>
                <div class="a-icon arrow-right browse-node-arrow" ng-show="nodeCtrl.node.hasChildren"></div>

                <div class="select-button-ungated ng-hide" ng-show="!nodeCtrl.isGated &amp;&amp; !nodeCtrl.node.hasChildren" ng-click="nodeCtrl.onSelectNode({node:nodeCtrl.node})">
                    <span class="a-button a-button-base a-button-small select-button"><span class="a-button-inner"><input class="a-button-input" type="submit"><span class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true">
                       Auswählen
                    </span></span></span>
                </div>

                <div class="gated-button ng-hide" ng-click="nodeCtrl.onRequestApproval({node:nodeCtrl.node})" ng-show="nodeCtrl.isGated &amp;&amp; !nodeCtrl.node.hasChildren">
                    <span class="a-button a-button-primary a-button-small select-button"><span class="a-button-inner"><input class="a-button-input" type="submit"><span class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true">
                        Freischaltung beantragen
                    </span></span></span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    <span>
</span></span></browse-node-component>
```

**The Result**

The last output is "done", then the script gets terminated and following message appears:

```
Message: Element 'input class="a-button-input" type="submit"' could not be scrolled into view
```

But I am unsure to whether I actually have to press that button. Am I pressing the right one? If so, how can I do it without errors?

I want to navigate through those categories, until i reach a child node and then press the select button of it. Yet I cant show the subcategories of toplevel categories with my code. Please give me a hint on which html-element I have to click on.

See here, for graphical information:

**Selenium and Python:**
[image: image taken from https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx3iw.jpg]

**Page when instance is opened with selenium:**
[image: image taken from https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx3iw.jpg]

Image Source : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx3iw.jpg

Comment: I do not know and have not tested this but I highly suspect the solution to your problem is that, as the error message says, you need the element to be visible to be clickable. This is referenced here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588096/selenium-web-driver-cannot-be-scrolled-into-view. To achieve this, apparently you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium

Comment: @AppliePie: Thanks, seems like my search got hanged up on clicking custom tags instead of the error message (which doesn't appear on any run).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below.

```
browse_node_button.location_once_scrolled_into_view
browse_node_button.click()
```

If the above does not work then you might have to use the JS to click on `browse_node_button`

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", browse_node_button)
```

Comment: And thanks again. I'll have to put your name into the boiler plate ;) Above solution did not work, JS did though.