# Choose item from dropdown menu with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I'm using Selenium to get some info in a webpage, but I need to choose an specific item in a dropdown menu list first. Here it is what the page looks like:

[image]

I want to click the "Tracker Availavility" option. I tried getting the class (highlighted in image) and change it's value, but that doesn't work... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit HTML Code:

```
<select class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse"> style="width: 100px; height: 33px; margin-left: 5px; border-radius: 2px;" ng-model="$ctrl.selectedScratchPad" ng-options="s.name for s in $ctrl.scratchPads track by s.name" ng-change="$ctrl.scratchPadSelected($ctrl.selectedScratchPad)"
<!-- ngIf: $ctrl.selectedScratchPad === null -->
<option label="G&T" value="G&T" selected="selected">G&T</option>
<option label="Relatório semanal" value="Relatório semanal" selected="selected">Relatório semanal</option>
<option label="CBs current" value="CBs current">CBs current</option>
<option label="Tracker Availability" value="Tracker Availability">Tracker Availability</option>
<option label="INV 5-1 Trackers target" value="INV 5-1 Trackers target">INV 5-1 Trackers target</option>
<option label="INV 5-1 Trackers current" value="INV 5-1 Trackers current">INV 5-1 Trackers current</option>
<option label="INV 5-1 Trackers availability" value="INV 5-1 Trackers availability">INV 5-1 Trackers availability</option>
<option label="PVSyst Input" value="PVSyst Input">PVSyst Input</option>
```

Comment: Also tried this: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='ng-valid ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse']/option[text()='Tracker Availability']").click()` but I get an error saying: "Unable to locate element".

Comment: Add the code and error to the post. Also, Add HTML code instead of the screenshot.

Comment: @SAhmed sorry for that. Just edited now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the option to click on the list item directly.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@ng-model='$ctrl.selectedScratchPad']/option[.='Tracker Availability']").click()
```

Comment: Thanks supputuri! That's perfect for me!

Comment: Hey man, now I just want to click a button `<label class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:5px" ng-click="$ctrl.save()" ng-disabled="$ctrl.processing || $ctrl.model.total === 0" title="Save"> <i class="fa fa-save"></i> </label>` after that but I keep getting that the button "could not be scrolled into view". I've changed your code using `WebDriverWait` but couldn't get rid of that... Any ideas?

Comment: Refer to my answer [how to click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876620/how-to-click-custom-html-tag-with-selenium) a element. you have to create element using xpath `//i[@class='fa fa-save']`. I would recommend open a new query when you have a different question, so that people look at the original post does not get confused.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clicking the selection you can select the option from a `<select>` element by using the `Select` class.

**Try this:**

```py
element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//select[@ng-model='$ctrl.selectedScratchPad']")))
dropdown = Select(element)
dropDown.select_by_visible_text("Tracker Availability")
```

For this, you have to import the following.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks S Ahmed! But I don't know why the code keeps giving me error, as I mentioned above, because of the class name...

Comment: That means the locator was wrong. I've edited the code. Try this one out.